# Can we import old seed phrases to the new Ledger Stax?

Tags: recovery, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

Ledger Nano devices have 24 words for a recovery or seed phrase. Will the new Ledger Stax hardware wallet also have 24 words? Can we import old seed phrases from a previous Nano device to the Ledger Stax?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the new Ledger Stax also has 24 words for a recovery or seed phrase since the official site states "Beware of phishing attacks, Ledger will never ask for the 24 words of your recovery phrase". Yes, you can import old seed phrases from a previous Nano device to the Ledger Stax by choosing to recover access to your existing assets by entering the Secret Recovery Phrase of your Ledger Nano S Plus or Ledger Nano X and transfer your crypto to your Ledger Stax.

See: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/7914685928221-Ledger-Stax-FAQs?docs=true

Comment: can the Ledger Stax import "Legacy" wallet addresses, as opposed to ones created with "Ledger Live"?